# Nuxt in vuejs render double css

Tags: css, vue.js, nuxt.js

My **Vue** application is using **Nuxt** for server side rendering and it renders 2 times CSS. How to avoid this situation?

```
<style data-vue-ssr-id="d7914c7a:0">
//Css1
</style>
<style data-vue-ssr-id="68eb569c:0">
//Css2
</style>
<style data-vue-ssr-id="0159269c:0">
//Css3
</style>
<style type="text/css">
//Css1
</style>
<style type="text/css">
//Css2
</style>
<style type="text/css">
//Css3
</style>
```

First I though it was generated by **LESS** since I use **LESS** for compiling my  **CSS**, but when I tried only **CSS**, it still renders double **CSS** code, for example:

```css
.ClassNameA {
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.ClassNameB > * {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

```css
.ClassNameA {
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.ClassNameB > * {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

Image from devtool:

Comment: We need to see the code that applies the CSS. It could be you are placing it in the wrong place causing double output.

Comment: it's inline or external css file?

Comment: Please add the Nuxt implementation...

Comment: @Deckerz : here is the code in css of 1 vue component: 
```
<style lang="less">
  @import "~@path-to-global-css/style1.less";
  @import "~@path-to-global-css/style2.less";
  @import "~@path-to-global-css/styling_mixins.less";
// Some CSS
</style>
```

Comment: @VikashPathak it's external css file

Comment: @Teocci you meant Nuxt.config.js?